# Why does this code use a *char as a buffer pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, char

In looking for circular buffer code to reuse, I've come across a use of char which confuses me

```
typedef struct CircularBuffer
{
    void *buffer;     // data buffer
    void *buffer_end; // end of data buffer
    size_t capacity;  // maximum number of items in the buffer
    size_t count;     // number of items in the buffer
    size_t sz;        // size of each item in the buffer
    void *head;       // pointer to head
    void *tail;       // pointer to tail
} CircularBuffer;

void cb_push_back(CircularBuffer *cb, const void *item)
{
    if(cb->count == cb->capacity)
        // handle error
        memcpy(cb->head, item, cb->sz);

    ////////////// here's the part I don't understand //////////
    cb->head = (char*)cb->head + cb->sz;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if(cb->head == cb->buffer_end)
        cb->head = cb->buffer;
    cb->count++;
}
```

Why cast this void pointer to a char? Is this some sort of C idiom (I have very limted C expereience)? A away convenient way to increment a pointer perhaps?

The use of a char for the position pointer comes up again in some different buffer code as well:

```
/**< Circular Buffer Types */
typedef unsigned char INT8U;
typedef INT8U KeyType;
typedef struct
{
    INT8U writePointer; /**< write pointer */
    INT8U readPointer;  /**< read pointer */
    INT8U size;         /**< size of circular buffer */
    KeyType keys[0];    /**< Element of ciruclar buffer */
} CircularBuffer;
```

Again, this looks like some sort of handy trick that C programmers know about, something about pointers being easy to manipulate if they're chars. But I'm really just speculating.

Comment: FYI:  The type is called a `char*`, not a `*char`.

Comment: this is the first time that I see the name of the struct as the name of the typedef, this is weird...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cast to `char *` is to make pointer arithmetic perform correctly if you want to move the pointer in one-byte steps; this always works because `char` have, by definition, the size of 1 byte. Pointer arithmetic with `void *` pointers, instead, is not defined by the C standard, because `void` doesn't specify a size for a single item.

Another common C idiom (related to this) is to use `unsigned char *` when you want to access some memory as "raw bytes" (the `unsigned` type lets you access the unsigned value of each byte without casts); it's often used also `typedef`ed (something along the lines of `typedef unsigned char byte;`) to make it extra clear that you don't want to interpret the memory as characters, but as raw bytes.

Answer (score 5):

A `char` has a size of one byte, so it (or `signed char` or `unsigned char`) is used when you want to manipulate some region of memory simply as an array of bytes.

Comment: So is there no standard  byte-sized (heh) numerical type then?

Answer (score 3):

Void pointers just point to a value and do not have type information. So it is not possible to perform addition on void pointers. Casting it to some other type is need for pointer arithmetic. Here casting void * to char * and then adding cb->sz, Moves forward by size bytes assuming size of char is 1 .

Comment: No assumption is required.  `sizeof(char) == 1` is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

The cast enables pointer arithmetic; without it, since `cb->head` is of type `void*`, the expression `cb->head + cb->sz` would have no meaning.

Once the pointer is cast to `char*`, the pointer addition `(char*)cb->head + cb->sz` means “the address of the object `cb->size` bytes past where `cb->head` points.